Is this section also speaking of TC and fMRI?
This section is about cognitive science, does them include also the branch which is called cognitive neuroscience?

Sorry. I'm confused. Could you clarify how this question relates to meta.cogsci?

@JeromyAnglim: This section is about cognitive science, does this include also the branch which is called cognitive neuroscience? Can I open question here about that? ps: Please, be patient, there is a big medical reason for which I'm asking this question..

Neuroscience is on topic.

Cognitive Sciences is a question and answer site for researchers,
  academics, students, and enthusiasts needing expert answers to
  advanced questions in the "cognitive sciences": I.e., cognitive
  science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry.


So I can ask information on TC, fRMI, EEG, rehabilitation and similar stuff? For example about Neuroplasticity and so on?

@Revious, yes you can.
